# Remove parentheses in start and end of JSON using javascript

Tags: php, json, trim, parentheses

I am doing an API request in PHP through curl. The result of my request is JSON. But, the JSON is between parentheses, like this:

```
({
    "version": "3.2.2 build 276 (20121126)",
    "type": "clipquery",
    "select": {
        "query": "world"
    },
    "limit": "",
    "numberofresults": 17,
    "results": [

    ],
    "errors": [

    ],
    "debug": {
        "runtime": 0.046874046325684
    } 
})
```

[JSONLint](http://pro.jsonlint.com) says that my JSON is invalid. And that's correct. But, I can't find how to remove the parentheses.

Comment: `trim($json, '()');`

Comment: How is this JSON being generated?

Comment: I have no idea. It is an external API.

Comment: @Mohammad it wasn't useful, because I voted it down. I don't know why I did, but I trust on my earlier choice.